# An object with type of value depending on the type of key

Tags: typescript

Let's assume this:

```
enum MouseType {
  PRODUCTIVITY = 1,
  GAMING = 2,
}

enum KeyboardType {
  PRODUCTIVITY = 3,
  GAMING = 4,
}

interface MouseSpec {
  buttons: number;
  dpi: number;
}

interface KeyboardSpec {
  keys: number;
}

type CustomData = {
  [key in MouseType | KeyboardType]: MouseSpec | KeyboardSpec;
}
```

How can I change CustomData to ensure that the last item triggers an error?

```
const data: CustomData = {
  [MouseType.PRODUCTIVITY]: { buttons: 4, dpi: 800 }, // ok
  [MouseType.GAMING]: { buttons: 6, dpi: 1600 }, // ok
  [KeyboardType.PRODUCTIVITY]: { keys: 78 }, // ok
  [KeyboardType.GAMING]: { keys: 120 }, // ok
  [MouseType.PRODUCTIVITY]: { keys: 999 }, // should not be ok
};
```

Comment: You're currently saying any key from either MouseType or KeyboardType can be a MouseSpec or a KeyboardSpec. I think you actually want the union between `{ [key in MouseType]: MouseSpec }` and `{ [key in KeyboardType]: KeyboardSpec }`, no?

Comment: Yes this is what I'd like to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem over here is, that

```
[key in MouseType | KeyboardType]: MouseSpec | KeyboardSpec
```

allow mapping KeyboardSpecs to MouseType.

A possible solution would be to create two seperate indexed types, which map Mouse/Keyboard-Types to their Specs:

```
type MouseData = {
    [key in MouseType]: MouseSpec;
}

type KeyBoardData = {
    [key in KeyboardType]: KeyboardSpec;
}
```

And then create your desired CustomData as a intersectiontype of the two indexed types:

```
type CustomData = MouseData & KeyBoardData
```

With this new CustomData type you would get your desired error message.

Comment: Ok thanks, this is working well.
Except for one detail...

If I try to access my object data `data[MouseType.PRODUCTIVITY]`, I get this ts error:
`Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'MouseType.PRODUCTIVITY' can't be used to index type 'CustomData'.
  Property '[MouseType.PRODUCTIVITY]' does not exist on type 'CustomData'`

Comment: I updated the anwser. CustomData is now an intersectiontype of MouseData & KeyBoardData.